# catch JSF Action with JQuery Submit

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jsf, jsf-2

I need catch JSF Action Event with JQuery submit function, I have the next code:

**JSF Code**

```
 <h:form id="seleccionPlanForm">
    <h:commandLink id="p1" title="seleccion 1" action="#{contrataBackingBean.selectPlanAction}">
      <f:param name="idPlan" value="1"/>
    </h:commandLink>
 </h:form>
```

---

**JQuery Code**

```
$("form").submit(function() { 
   alert("Hello World");
});
```

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "catch"? You want some Javascript code to be executed BEFORE the action is made? Or you want to actually control if the request is made or not?

Comment: I need to make a generic function to catch all forms submit my application with JQuery JSF

Answer (score 0):

1) force to click your button jsf, you can hide your button with style="display:none"

**JQuery Example**

```
  $('#input').change(
    function(){
       $('#clientIDOFActionButton').click();
    }
 );
```

Important: you must retrieve clientID of UIComponent, no Server UIComponentID.

2) Work with richfaces, with jsFunction component and call with js/JQuery for start the  execution of jsFunction Component

**JSF Code**

```
                  <a4j:actionparam name="param_name" assignTo="#{bean.someProperty2}"/>

       </a4j:jsFunction>
```

**Java Script Binding**

```
 <body onload="callScript()">
```

http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_jsFunction.html

here you can see, how to action and actionListener attributes works with jsFunction component:

http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/jsFunction.jsf?tab=info&cid=292171

you can share more code?

Comment: You can do this using plain JavaScript or even using jQuery. Also, since OP's using JSF 2 (as noted in the tags on question) you can recommend using RichFaces 4 or PrimeFaces 3 for the task, but recognizing that these libraries will just handle the JavaScript/jQuery cumbersome code for you behind the scenes.